# grunt-contrib-cssmin missing _stream_transform module

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I get the following error when trying to run css minification from GruntJs and I have no clue why.

```
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...ERROR 
>> Error: Cannot find module '_stream_transform
```

What is the origin of this error message? I've search through the cssmin.js file and can't find a single reference to that module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've the same problem.
Go to grunt-contrib-cssmin/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/browserify-zlib
and install the readable-stream module

> > npm install readable-stream

Then modify this file grunt-contrib-cssmin/node_modules/maxmin/node_modules/gzip-size/node_modules/browserify-zlib/src/index.js

- replace:

  > > var Transform = require('_stream_transform');
- by:

  > > var Transform = require('readable-stream').Transform;

It works for me and I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 6):

Hoang's answer should not be acceptable, because it requires you to locally make changes to a node module from the NPM registry.

What happens when someone pulls your repository, and runs NPM install ... or if you update the module?

The fix: I came across the same problem and found that simply updating node (using NVM in my case) fixed it for me.